# Generating Qr Code by passing document.createElement doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, qr-code

I am working on a project that generates random qr code. This the plugin I am using http://davidshimjs.github.io/qrcodejs/

```
function createQrImage(qrValue){

    //option1
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");

    //option2
    var qrDiv = document.getElementById("myDivId");

    //only option 2 works
    var qrcode = new QRCode(qrDiv);

    qrcode.makeCode(qrValue)
}
```

Creating new QR code using options 2 works fine but if I pass the option 1 variable, no QR Code is generated. No errors in console either.

Comment: Do you need to create a new element on the fly or can you pass your createQrImage function a div that exists on the DOM? It either wants an ID or wants the div to exist somewhere already it seems.

Comment: Have you tried `document.body.appendChild(newDiv);` before  calling `QRCode`?

Comment: You aren't adding `newDiv` to the document anywhere.

Comment: Thank you so much @imvain2. It work after adding that code. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my comment, since newDiv isn't added to the DOM anywhere, referencing it won't affect the output. So you will need to append it to the body before using it.

```
function createQrImage(qrValue){

    //option1
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    document.body.appendChild(newDiv);

    //option2
    var qrDiv = document.getElementById("myDivId");

    //only option 2 works
    var qrcode = new QRCode(qrDiv);

    qrcode.makeCode(qrValue)
}
```